# My top-bar avatar has become a victim of continental drift

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

It would appear that today my avatar across all Stack Exchange sites has decided to distance itself from my relatively insignificant reputation.

[image: paddingggg]

I suppose I don't necessarily blame it—I wouldn't want to be associated with a mere 1.2k rep on Meta, either—but it does feel a little bit excessive. Can somebody push it back into place, please?

Comment: Who knew `.gravatar-wrapper-48` wasn't for 24 pixel-wide images?!

Comment: To SE devs: please stop messing with spacing today, thanks? Love, hichris123

Comment: At least the high-rep users know what it feels like to be a low-rep user.  Revenge has been paid. >:)

Comment: @hichris123 - I put in extra padding somewhere, but only for you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was a (slightly) botched attempt at making the avatar images more high-DPI friendly.

The high-DPI size escaped out into a CSS class, where it had no business.

It has now been put in lock-down, will be severely reprimanded and kept under observation.

With you in the next build.

Comment: I wouldn't like to make a dev mistake at Stack..."*It has now been put in lock-down, will be severely reprimanded and kept under observation*" I'd have thought just a quiet word would be enough...

Comment: @James - no, no. That's just how we deal with errant integers.

Comment: Shouldn't numbers be drawn and **quartered**?